# Loop de frases de status em HTML

Tags: html

Estou editando uma função de cancelamento de arquivos, e hoje ela mostra apenas o status "Aguardando...", conforme o código:

```
&js<
            cancelEvent = "";
            $(".ui-overlay").show();
            $("#retorno").empty().html("<img src='../loader.gif' width='14' align='absmiddle'> Aguardando...");
            $.get("../javascript/Cancela.php#(qs)#",function(data){
                 $("#retorno").empty().html(data);
                     if(data == 1) {
                        processaEvento('#(NF)#','#(DESC)#','#(DT1)#','#(DT2)#','#(OP)#');
                     } else {
                        alert("Não foi possível realizar o cancelamento");
                        document.getElementById("btSalvar").disabled = false;
                        document.getElementById("btSalvar").value = "Salvar";
                     }
            });
            $(".ui-overlay").hide();
        >
```

Eu quero acrescentar uma sequencia de frases de carregamento, como *"Aguarde..."*, *"Efetuando o cancelamento..."*, *"Finalizando o procedimento..."*, para o usuário pode acompanhar o passo a passo.

Só consigo fazer isso com javascript? Ou alguma sugestão diferente?

Comment: Como é que é isso? É um Ajax?

Comment: poderia postar seu código completo, por favor?

Comment: Editei com o bloco de código inteiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Javascript` é a melhor opção, pois você pode alterar o texto de acordo com eventos, mostrando mensagens diferentes para cada status.

Mas você pode usar `css` para mudar o conteúdo da mensagem usando a propriedade `content` (veja mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/content)

E se você quiser só trocar as mensagens sem se preocupar com um evento certo, apenas em um determinado tempo por exemplo você pode usar uma animação do **css3**, com `@keyframes` (veja mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Criei um exemplo prático que faz a troca dos textos em 30s

```css
h1:before{
    content: 'Aguarde...';
    font-size: 200%;
    animation-name: head;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes head {
    0% {content: "Aguarde..."}
    25% {content: "Mensagem 2"}
    50% {content: "3a mensagem"}
    75% {content: "Quarta mensagem"}
    100% {content: "Mensagem Final"}
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Genial Ricardo! Não necessito de um evento ao certo... por isso os keyframes são perfeitos, não tinha nem ideia da existência deles, muito obrigado.